# What is the best way to determine if Object has been changed?

Tags: java, hashcode, savechanges

I made some "save" bean functionality in my Java Web Application (JSF1.2, RichFaces). It is using JAXB to turn it into an XML string and then it is stored in the database. If the user loads this back, I want to notify the user if the (bean)content is changed and it should be saved again.

My idea is to override the `hashCode()` function 'with' `org.apache.commons.lang.builder.HashCodeBuilder`, however I have lots of fields and child elements.
Is there any other way to handle this kind of functionality?

**EDIT**

"Comparison" is done on another view!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In case you go for an hashCode-based solution, remember to modify your equals() method accordingly.

Apart from that I agree that you should add a "modified" flag at the instance level, be sure that all changes go through setter methods, and modify each setter so that if it receives a value which is different from the one already stored in the property it sets the flag. Clear this every time you have written or reread the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a `boolean dirty;` flag to the bean, set it to `true` in your setters and clear it during a reload and after a save.

Comment: Well, in your setters and in any other methods that modify any variables in any way. Or make sure that your setters are the only such methods.

Comment: Problem is that the user can submit the same values, causing all the setter methods to be called.

Comment: That works if the setter examines whether the value has been changed. Still a lot of redundant code, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on `hashCode` alone to determine if an object has been changed. That is, just because the object has the same `hashCode` as before, does NOT mean that it has not been changed.

Comment: But let's say a field that's used in the `hashCode` calculation has been changed. Than I can rely on the object having a different `hashCode` than before, can't I?

Comment: @user321068 Not necessarily. A good hash function will make it unlikely for the object to keep the same hash code after being modified, but this is not a strict guarantee.

Comment: user321068, the answer above answers your question, doesn't it? The only guarantee is this: if an object has *not* changed, its `hashCode` remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java's MD5 functionality:

```
MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
digest.update(myObject);
byte[] hash = digest.digest();
```